# Why is the 2nd norm of a complex vector equal to the norm of the same vector multiplied from left by its in dimensions corresponding fourier matrix?

Tags: normed-spaces, inner-products, fourier-transform

The question is:

[image]

with the fourier matrix defined as

[image]

and the supplied solution is

[image]

I get the first step, because the fourier matrix multiplied by its inverse results in the identity matrix. But I am lost by the second. Can someone show me why the dot product of two vectors is equal to the dot product of a multiplication of an invertable matrix to both vectors?

**Update after answered with relevant definitions**

This matlab script demonstrates the definition used in the second step

```
N = 4;
X = complex(rand(N, N), rand(N,N));
z = [3;5;7;8]
dot(X*z,z)
dot(z,ctranspose(X)*z) % the result of these last two lines is always equal
```

1. The conjugate transpose $A^*$ of a matrix $A$ is
   $$(A^*)_{i,j} = (A^H)_{i,j} = \overline {A_{j,i}}$$
2. A complex square matrix $U$ is unitary if its conjugate transpose $U^*$ is also its inverse
   $$UU^* = UU^{-1} = I$$

Comment: The DFT matrix is unitary which is that first step. The second step is the definition of the adjoint of a matrix.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Could you point me to the definition you are talking about?

Comment: One of the equivalent definitions of the adjoint of a matrix is: $A^*$ is defined to be the linear map satisfying $\langle A x,y\rangle = \langle x, A^* y\rangle$.

Comment: I found that definition online, but I dont understand how that is applied here. In the definition one matrix is removed from the left side of the dot product and another matrix is multiplied to the right side of the dot product. In the solution there is one matrix on the left side, the identitiy, and in the next step there are two new matricies multiplied to both sides of the dot product.

Comment: I answered below instead of having an extended conversation in comments that fully answers the question.

Comment: Please, English.

Comment: @K.defaoite In fact, there is no requirement on Math SE that posts be in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the step

$$ \langle z, z\rangle = \langle F^*F z,z\rangle, $$

the fact that the DFT matrix $F$ is unitary is used: $F^*F = I$ so that $z = F^*F z$.

In the step

$$ \langle F^* F z,z\rangle = \langle Fz, Fz\rangle, $$

the definition of the adjoint is used: $\langle A^* x,y\rangle = \langle x, Ay\rangle$ so that $\langle F^* Fz, z\rangle = \langle Fz, Fz\rangle$.